# Creating a dynamic Variable in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

am try to create a dynamic variable in CodeIgniter. i have a model that fetched data from database and display it in the view. normally it will be something like this
            $data['query'] = $this->mdl_store_accounts->get('id');
and the access the object of the data with $query.

But this is what i want to achieve below. i passing variable (a to e) in a loop in the place of (query).

```
function manage()
{
    $query = $this->mdl_store_accounts->get('id');
    $sport = $query->row('sport');
    $slots = $query->row('slots');

    $_start = 1;
    $_end = 4;
    $q = 1; 
    for ($z='a'; $z <= 'e' ; $z++) { 
        if ($sport == $q) {
            // echo $q; die();
            $available_slot = $slots * ($sport - 1) ;  //slots used and available slot calculation to get next range
            $_start = $available_slot + 1 ;  //slots used and available slot calculation to get next range
            $_end = $available_slot + 3;
            // echo $start . ' and ' . $end; die();
            $data[$z] = $this->mdl_courses->_custom_query('SELECT * from courses WHERE id BETWEEN '.$_start.' AND '.$_end.' ORDER BY rand()');
        } elseif($q == 1 and $q !== $sport) {
            $_start = 1 ;  //slots used and available slot calculation to get next range
            $_end = 4;
            $data[$z] = $this->mdl_courses->_custom_query('SELECT * from courses WHERE id BETWEEN '.$_start.' AND '.$_end.' ORDER BY rand()');
        } elseif($q == 2 and $q !== $sport) {
            $_start = 5 ;  //slots used and available slot calculation to get next range
            $_end = 9;
            $data[$z] = $this->mdl_courses->_custom_query('SELECT * from courses WHERE id BETWEEN '.$_start.' AND '.$_end.' ORDER BY rand()');
        }
        $q++;
    } }
```

the access it with dynamic variable in my view like this;

```
$query = "$";
${$query . 'a'} = $a;
foreach ($a->result() as $rows) {
$query++;                                              
$a++;
```

i have tried array and this $$a. Yet not working. Am the getting error
Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I would break this apart to test. Does your query variable concat/assign correctly? Are you actually querying the database, or simply generating the statement? Can you print the results? How about a `$a->row_count()`?

Comment: Just to clarify: var_dump($a); outputs NULL?

Comment: var_dump($a) produces

object(CI_DB_mysqli_result)[27]
  public 'conn_id' => 
    object(mysqli)[15]
      public 'affected_rows' => null
      public 'client_info' => null
      public 'client_version' => null
      public 'connect_errno' => null
      public 'connect_error' => null
      public 'errno' => null
      public 'error' => null
      public 'error_list' => null
      public 'field_count' => null
      public 'host_info' => null
      public 'info' => null
      public 'insert_id' => null
      public 'server_info' => null
      ....
there is more

Comment: without this :
$query = "$";
${$query . 'a'} = $a;
foreach ($a->result() as $rows) {
$query++;                                              
$a++; 
i get my query output correctly by just referencing the variable array like this:
foreach ($a->result() as $rows) {
$rows->name;
}
but what i want is to do a loop that changes the variable array like ($a, $b, $c, $d, $e) since the controller query is being looped through (a -e)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. Can you describe the value of $a in the view? Also, why are you running `$query++` and `$a++` when those are not ints?